# Word won't open a link because of "Restrictions on my computer", I have put no restrictions on my computer

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word

When I try to open a link in word, I get this error:

[image]

The problem is, I'm the administrator. And I have put *no* limits whatsoever on my computer.

Why does this show up?

Comment: try this: http://www.slipstick.com/problems/this-operation-has-been-cancelled-due-to-restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the command prompt and execute below commands in order:

`REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.htm /ve /d htmlfile /f`

`REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.html /ve /d htmlfile /f`

`REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.shtml /ve /d htmlfile /f`

`REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.xht /ve /d htmlfile /f`

`REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.xhtml /ve /d htmlfile /f`

Or read the following link:

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/outlook-office-hyperlink-restrictions-error/

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that these reg edits set internet explorer as the default browser.

Comment: Yes, Exactly...